# Как сделать так, что бы открывать картинку по клику

Tags: javascript, html, popup

[image: как должно выглядеть открытие картинки]

Мне необходимо понять как делать открытие по нажатию на картинку, я не гуру в js и не особо понимаю как сделать это...
Кому не сложно могли бы мне объяснить, либо дать материал который мне поможет понять как это делать.

Какие параметры у меня в задаче:

1. Необходимо что бы при нажатие плавно разворачивался popup с
   картинкой.
2. Вёрстка адаптивная, без полосы прокрутки при изменении ширины окна.
3. Максимальная ширина открытой картинки — 75vw, максимальная высота —
   75vh. Файловая структура организована по БЭМу

Всем спасибо кто поможет!.

```js
// Денамические карточки.
const initialCards = [

    {
        name: 'Архыз',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Челябинская область',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/chelyabinsk-oblast.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Иваново',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/ivanovo.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Камчатка',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kamchatka.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Холмогорский район',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kholmogorsky-rayon.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Байкал',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/baikal.jpg'
    }
];

// Подключенные переменные.
let buttonEditPopup = document.querySelector('.profile__edit-button');
let buttonEditPopupClose = document.querySelector('.popup__close');
let editPopup = document.querySelector('.popup');
let formElement = document.querySelector('.popup__form');
let buttonAddPopup = document.querySelector('.profile__add-button');
let buttonAddPopupClose = document.querySelector('.popup-add__close');
let addPopup = document.querySelector('.popup-add');
let formAddCardsElement = document.querySelector('.popup__form-card');

let inputUserName = document.querySelector('.popup__text_user_name');
let inputUserSpecialty = document.querySelector('.popup__text_user_specialty');
let profileName = document.querySelector('.profile__name');
let profileSpecialty = document.querySelector('.profile__specialty');

const initialCardsList = document.querySelector('.cards');
const templateElements = document.querySelector('.template');
const cardsElements = document.querySelector('.cards__card');
const inputLinkElements = document.querySelector('.popup__text-link');
const inputTitleElements = document.querySelector('.popup__text-title');
let imgPopup = document.querySelector('.popup-image');
let fullSizeImage = document.querySelector('.popup__title-image');
let fullSizeImageLink = document.querySelector('.popup__image-link');


// Модальное окно 'редактирование профиля'
function openedPopup(modal) {
    modal.classList.add('popup_opened');
}

function closePopup(modal) {
    modal.classList.remove('popup_opened');
}

function formAddSubmitHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const inputTextLink = inputLinkElements.value;
    const inputTextTitle = inputTitleElements.value;
    let data = {
        name: inputTextTitle,
        link: inputTextLink
    };
    const newItem = composeItem(data);
    initialCardsList.prepend(newItem);
    formAddCardsElement.reset();
    closePopup(addPopup);
}

// Функция гинераций карточек
function renderList() {
    const listItemCard = initialCards.map(composeItem);

    initialCardsList.append(...listItemCard);
}



function composeItem(item) {
    const newItem = templateElements.content.cloneNode(true);
    const headerElemets = newItem.querySelector('.cards__title');
    const linkElemets = newItem.querySelector('.cards__image');
    headerElemets.textContent = item.name;
    linkElemets.setAttribute('src', item.link);
    newItem.querySelector('.cards__rectangle-like').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        evt.target.classList.toggle('cards__rectangle-like_active');
    });
    const removeButton = newItem.querySelector('.cards__rectangle-remove');
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
    return newItem;
}

function removeItem(event) {
    const targetElement = event.target;
    const targetItem = targetElement.closest('.cards__card');
    targetItem.remove();
}

renderList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<!-- Вверх сайта -->

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pages/index.css" />
    <title>Mesto</title>
</head>

    <!-- Модальное окно -->
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__container">
            <button class="popup__close" type="reset"></button>
            <h2 class="popup__title">Редактировать профиль</h2>
            <form class="popup__form" action="form-user" name="form-user">
                <input class="popup__text popup__text_user_name" type="text" id="name" name="name" required
                    minlength="4" maxlength="28" />
                <input class="popup__text popup__text_user_specialty" type="text" id="specialty" name="specialty"
                    required minlength="4" maxlength="28" />
                <button class="popup__save" type="submit">Сохранить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popup popup-add">
        <div class="popup__container">
            <button class="popup__close popup-add__close" type="reset"></button>
            <h2 class="popup__title">Новое место</h2>
            <form class="popup__form-card" action="form-card" name="form-card">
                <input class="popup__text popup__text-title" type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Название публикаций" />
                <input class="popup__text popup__text-link" type="text" id="link" name="link" required
                    placeholder="Ссылка на картинку" />
                <button class="popup__save popup-add__save" type="submit">Создать</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popup popup-image">
        <div class="popup__container">
            <button class="popup__close" type="reset"></button>
            <img class="popup__image popup__image-link" src="${item.link}" alt="">
            <p class="popup__title popup__title-image">${item.name}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Template -->
    <template class="template">
        <div class="cards__card">
            <button class="cards__rectangle-remove" type="button"></button>
            <img class="cards__image" src="" alt="" />
            <div class="cards__discription">
                <h2 class="cards__title"></h2>
                <button class="cards__rectangle-like" type="button"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </template>

    <!-- Подключение js и других скриптов -->
    <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пользуйся Fancybox. Не нужно придумывать велосипед, который за тебя придумали уже. Максимально прост в настройке и имеет кучу "плюшек"
Ссылка: [fancyBox 3](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но задача стоит сделать "велосипед"